# Show that if $a$ has order $3\bmod p$ then $a+1$ has order $6\bmod p$.

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $a$ has order $3\bmod p$ then $a+1$  has order $6\bmod p$. I know I am supposed to use primitive roots but I think this is where I am getting caught up. The definition of primitive root is "if $a$ is a least residue and the order of $a\bmod p$ is $\phi(m)$ then $a$ is a primitive root of $m$. But I really am not sure how to use this to my advantage in solving anything.

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332325/if-p-is-prime-a-in-bbb-z-orda-p-3-then-how-to-find-orda1-p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note that if $a=1$, $a$ has order $1$. Thus, we can assume $a\ne1$. Furthermore, $p\ne2$ since no element mod $2$ has order $3$. Therefore, $-1\ne1\pmod{p}$.
$$
\begin{align}
(a+1)^3
&=a^3+3a^2+3a+1\\
&=1+3a^2+3a+1\\
&=-1+3(1+a+a^2)\\
&=-1+3\frac{a^3-1}{a-1}\\
&=-1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(a+1)^3=-1$ and $(a+1)^6=1$. (Shortened a la ccorn). 
$$
\begin{align}
(a+1)^2
&=a^2+2a+1\\
&=a+(a^2+a+1)\\
&=a+\frac{a^3-1}{a-1}\\
&=a\\
&\ne1
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(a+1)^2\ne1$.

Thus, $(a+1)$ has order $6$.

Comment: $(a+1)^6=1$ also follows easily from $(a+1)^3=-1$

Comment: @ccorn: indeed it does, but I had already written the part for $(a+1)^6$. I guess I could shorten the answer. Thanks.

Comment: With the edit made the (a+1)^{2} is not needed right? If it is I don't  understand.

Comment: @Kathy: we still have to show that $a+1$ doesn't have order $2$. We could argue that if $(a+1)^2=1$ and $(a+1)^3=-1$, then $a+1=-1$; that is, $a=-2$. Since $a^3=1$ we have that $-8\equiv1\pmod{p}$, which implies that $p\mid9$, whence $p=3$. Since there are no elements of order $3$ mod $3$, we could stop. Personally, I think the argument in my answer is simpler.

Comment: Is there a problem with this answer? Just wondering if the downvote means something needs fixing.

Comment: @robjohn downvote probably for $=$ sign. you should use $\equiv$ instead.

Comment: @robjohn also why are there no elements of order $3$ modulo $3$? this is not clear to me.

Comment: There are only $2$ non-zero elements mod $3$. Thus, the greatest possible order of any element would be $2$.

Answer (score 1):

ord_$pa=3\iff p$ divides $(a^3-1)=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$

But $p\not\mid (a-1)$ as ord_$pa=3 $

$\displaystyle\implies a^2+a+1\equiv0\pmod p$
$\displaystyle\iff a(a+1)\equiv-1\pmod p$

**Method** $1:$

$\implies a^3(a+1)^3\equiv-1\pmod p\implies (a+1)^3\equiv-1$ and $(a+1)^6\equiv1$

$\implies $ord_$p(a+1)\mid 6$ but does not divide $3$

If ord_$p(a+1)\mid 2, (a+1)^2\equiv1\pmod p$ and $a^2(a+1)^2\equiv1\pmod p\implies a^2\equiv1$ which is impossible as ord$_pa=3$

$\implies $ord$_p(a+1)=6$

**Method** $2:$

$\displaystyle a(a+1)\equiv-1\pmod p\iff a+1\equiv (-a)^{-1}\pmod p$

Again as $a^3\equiv1\pmod p, (-a)^3=-a^3\equiv-1\pmod p\implies (-a)^6\equiv1\implies $ord$_p(-a)=6$

Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215024/find-ord-m-b2-if-ord-m-a-10-and-ab-equiv-1-pmod-m/215031#215031),  ord$_p\{(-a)^{-1}\})=$ord$_p(-a)=6$

Comment: why would $ \text{ord}_{p}a=3\implies p\nmid (a-1)$?